# state of unitization of C*-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I have a question: if $\phi$ is a state of $\tilde{A}$ (unitization of a $C*$-algebra $A$), is it true that the restriction of $\phi$ to $A$ is also a state?

I'm asking this because I was trying to prove that (notation: $S(B)$ is the set of all states of a $C*$-algebra $B$):

\begin{equation}
S(Ã)=\{\tilde{\phi}; \phi \in S(A)\} \cup \{\phi_\infty\},
\end{equation}

where $\phi_\infty(a+\lambda 1)=\lambda$.

What I did was to consider a state $\tau$ of $\tilde{A}$. If the restriction of $\tau$ to $A$ is zero, then is easy to show that $\tau$ equals to $\phi_\infty$.

Now, if the restriction of $\tau$ to $A$ is not zero, i was not able to prove that it is in fact a state of $A$.

Maybe there is another way of showing the equality, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true that the restriction of a state from the unitization is a state.

For instance let $A=C_0(\mathbb R)$ and  $\phi(f+\lambda 1)=\frac{f(0)}2+\lambda$. It is trivial to see that $\phi$ is a state, since
$$
\phi=\tfrac12\,\big[\phi_0+\phi_\infty\big],
$$
where $\phi_0(g)=g(0)$. But $\phi|_A(f)=\frac{f(0)}2$, so $\phi|_A$ is not a state.